# Do I need to call stream close method when I use using pattern

Tags: c#, .net

Do I need to call stream close method when I use using pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't *need* to (though there's no harm in being explicit).  If you're disposing the stream it'll also close it...however, you may still want to close it *earlier* than the dispose, if that's the case still call `.Close()`.

Comment: Dispose and Close are the same (they call each-other).  If you want to close it early, just moves the `using`'s `}`.

Answer (score 1):

In case of the `Stream` - No. The `Dispose` method does call the `Close`.

Answer (score 1):

No `using` will calls dispose, and all known stream in c# has Close in their dispose, but if is your own stream and you didn't implement it yes you should.

Answer (score 0):

For connections, no. For reader, yes.

Comment: your connection will not be closed unless you close the reader - even if it is in a using().

Answer (score 0):

The disassembled content of the `Dispose` method in `System.IO.Stream`

```
public void Dispose()
{
    this.Close();
}
```

So the answer would be no.

Answer (score 0):

No, in fact, `using` is equal to the following:

```
using(Stream stream = new Stream()){
……
}

Stream stream = null
try
{
 stream = new Stream();
}
finally
{
   stream.Dispose();
}
```

you can look up IL.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. It concerns the `Close` method, rather than the `Dispose` method.